# localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare does not seem to work with swedish characters

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sorting, localization

I'm trying to sort an array alphabetically. In the swedish alphabet the letter Å is third last letter in the alphabet so the below array should be sorted like `A, B, Å` but instead it is sorted like `A, Å, B`. What could be the reason for this behaviour?

```
NSArray *test = @[@"Å", @"A", @"B"];

NSArray *sortedTest = [test sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]; 
// Output is A, Å, B
```

Comment: Is localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare: in the documentation? I haven't found it.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: [localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the current locale is not the Swedish locale?

It works as expected if you explicitly use a Swedish locale for sorting the strings:

```
NSArray *test = @[@"Å", @"A", @"B"];
NSLocale *swedish = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"sv"];

NSArray *sortedTest = [test sortedArrayWithOptions:0
                                   usingComparator:^(NSString  *v1, NSString *v2) {
    return [v1 compare:v2 options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                 range:NSMakeRange(0, [v1 length])
                locale:swedish];
}];

// Output: A, B, Å
```

Comment: Ah of course that might be the case. Will try this in awhile. Thanks.