# Sorting an array with unicode strings

Tags: arrays, sorting, swift, unicode, unicode-string

I have an array with 3 names.

```
var patients = ["Kund Karlsson", "Test Vid behov", "Test Övrigt"]
```

I need to sort these names alphabetically. This is the result its supposed to be ordered in.

1. Kund Karlsson
2. Test Vid behov
3. Test Övrigt

I sort the array like this `patients.sort({ $0 < $1 })` but I get the wrong order.

1. Kund Karlsson
2. Test Övrigt
3. Test Vid behov

I assume this is caused by that unicode letter `Ö`.

Is there a way handle sorting when you have unicode characters in strings?

Thank you.

Comment: the 'Ö' is threated like 'O' in many languages, what system local are you on?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176943/localizedcaseinsensitivecompare-does-not-seem-to-work-with-swedish-characters ?

Comment: @Console I'm on `en_US` locale. I set the locale to `sv_SE` like in the accepted answer below and it works.

Comment: @MartinR That was it. Kirsteins's answer is pretty much the Swift version of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the **Ö** is treated as **O** in English, but thats might not be true for all languages. You can use the following:

```
patients.sort {
    $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
}
```

Results depends on you system's locale. To use specific locale:

```
var patients = ["Kund Karlsson", "Test Vid behov", "Test Övrigt"]
let locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "sv_SE")
patients.sort {
    let str1 = $0 as NSString
    let str2 = $1 as NSString

    return str1.compare(str2, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: NSMakeRange(0, str1.length), locale: locale) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just tried it but unfortunately it doesn't seem to have any effect on it. Still getting the incorrect ordered list.

Comment: As I said it depends on you current system locale. It will be different for `en_US` and `sv_SE`. See the updated answer to use specific locale.

Comment: This worked when I tested it on a playground but I'm trying to display the sorted array in a tableview but the sorting doesn't seem to happen there. Any idea why that might be? I uploaded my project to [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vzc1uc5xwjjdyhh/SortTest.zip?dl=0) if you want to take a quick look at it.

Comment: Sorry `range` code was messed up. Fixed in updated version. I have no clue why it worked in playgrounds.

Comment: Works perfectly! I assume the range parameter defines how far the comparison is done in strings, correct?

Comment: This will fail on 'ü' as in swedish ü is the same as y in sorting, (i didn't tried it but according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedish_orthography it should)

Comment: @Isuru yes, that is true.