# How can I sort by Turkish characters on IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have an `ios` application which have members in `Parse.com`. These members have name and surname. I used `'orderByAscending'` method and this method sorted by name and surname.

Here is my code:

```
PFQuery *getMembersQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Member"];
[getMembersQuery orderByAscending:@"firstName,lastName"];
```

My problem is, our country has special characters on alphabet which is `Ş,Ö,Ü` etc. I want to sort by `Turkish` alphabet. Is there anybody can help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sort descriptor like this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *lastDescriptor =
            [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:last
                                        ascending:YES
                                         selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

See Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-SW5) on this topic.

Also there are a lot of SO questions:

[localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare does not seem to work with swedish characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176943/localizedcaseinsensitivecompare-does-not-seem-to-work-with-swedish-characters)

Edit:
In your case (I'm too not familiar with Parse.) this have to look like this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *languageDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"... Key with that you want to sort your object(e.g Name)..." ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Member"];
NSArray *sortedMembers = [[query findObjects] sortArrayUsingDescriptors:@[languageDescriptor]];
```

Edit:
As I see Parse provides easier way to do this job:

```
NSSortDescriptor *languageDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"... Key that you want to sort..." ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSArray *sortedMembers = [[[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Member"] orderBySortDescriptors:@[languageDescriptor]] findObjects];
```

HTH.

Comment: First of all, thank you for replying. How can I adapt it to my code? You can see my code in my question.

Comment: What is your NSLocale value? Maybe this is the problem? If use simulator sometimes you need to change locale in Xcode scheme settings.